# How to Use UserControl Inside CustomControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, user-controls, custom-controls

I'm Developing Custom GridView Control.Which has select list in header, just like excel. As excel like filter, one of options are "custom filter". in this case i want to show a little control which i designed in as user control as ascx.
now when i want to use that user control in my custom control . i use this code :

```
 protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {

        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        AADQuickCustomFilter CustomFilter = (AADQuickCustomFilter)uc.LoadControl("~/AADQuickCustomFilter.ascx");
        TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        CustomFilter.RenderControl(hw);

        writer.Write(tw.ToString());
        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }
```

unfortunately i got error as **An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The file '/AADQuickCustomFilter.ascx' does not exist.** 
[image]

So Please help me , where is the problem. what i did wrong?
Thanks experts

Comment: Here i overridden RenderControl Of my Custom Control

Comment: You have to specify path from root of your site, is your ascx there?

Comment: Help me with code snip please @CrudaLilium

Comment: Your code should be fine, maybe don't use "~/" at the start, but this looks like your ascx is part of library and not in your site, can you please copy your ascx into the root of your site and see if it works?

Comment: @CrudaLilium

 I Did. I Test ~/ , ./ , ../ , / And nothing before AADQuickCustomFiler.


But Not Works

Comment: Alright and is your AADQuickCustomFiler.ascx located inside the roof of your site? Not inside your bin folder, but directly in your root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134893/discussion-between-crudalilium-and-user1998368).

Comment: You've included it in your grid custom control correct? That's not going to be in the root directory of your application. I can't give much guidance since I haven't used this feature in like a decade, but you need to embed the user control in the dll, and reference it as an embedded resource. It may be easier though to create it as another server control and then over-ride it's render method to generate all the html/css/js you need. FYI, you'll need to embed all your .js and .css files into the dll and reference them as embedded files.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick Thanks

Comment: @CrudaLilium Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is Answer.
At First i create class to Register ascx files as embed resource as this code :

```
    using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AADGridView
{
    public class AssemblyResourceProvider : VirtualPathProvider
    {
        string mResourcePrefix;

        public AssemblyResourceProvider() : this("EmbeddedWebResource")
        {
        }

        public AssemblyResourceProvider(string prefix)
        {
            mResourcePrefix = prefix;
        }

        private bool IsAppResourcePath(string virtualPath)
        {
            String checkPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(virtualPath);
            return checkPath.StartsWith("~/" + mResourcePrefix + "/",
                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            return (IsAppResourcePath(virtualPath) ||
                    base.FileExists(virtualPath));
        }

        public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
        {
            if (IsAppResourcePath(virtualPath))
                return new AssemblyResourceVirtualFile(virtualPath);
            else
                return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }

        public override CacheDependency
               GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath,
               IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies,
               DateTime utcStart)
        {
            if (IsAppResourcePath(virtualPath))
                return null;
            else
                return base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath,
                       virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
        }
    }

    class AssemblyResourceVirtualFile : VirtualFile
    {
        string path;

        public AssemblyResourceVirtualFile(string virtualPath) : base(virtualPath)
        {
            path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(virtualPath);
        }

        public override Stream Open()
        {
            string[] parts = path.Split('/');
            string assemblyName = parts[2];
            string resourceName = parts[3];
            assemblyName = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, assemblyName);
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName);
            if (assembly == null) throw new Exception("Failed to load " + assemblyName);
            Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
            if (s == null) throw new Exception("Failed to load " + resourceName);
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just Override the constractor of your custom control like this :

```
 public AADExcelFilterGridView() : base()


    {System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new AssemblyResourceProvider(ResourcePrefix));
}
```

And Then

```
 static string mResourcePrefix = "EmbeddedWebResource";

    public static string ResourcePrefix
    {
        get
        {
            return mResourcePrefix;
        }

        set
        {
            mResourcePrefix = value;
        }
    }
```

Now, Just need to add your User Control to Your Custom Control Rendering Like above :

```
 protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {

        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        AADQuickFilter CustomFilter = (AADQuickFilter)uc.LoadControl("~/EmbeddedWebResource/AADGridView.dll/AADGridView.AADQuickFilter.ascx");
        TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        CustomFilter.RenderControl(hw);

        writer.Write(tw.ToString());
        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }
```

That is all you got, Hope useful.
Thanks for very good comments of experts.